# How to use the phrase "tant et si bien"

Tags: expressions

> Elle a marchandé **tant et si bien** **que** l'agent immobilier a diminué le prix de la maison de moitié.

I’m wondering how this phrase differs in meaning from saying:

> Elle a marchandé **tellement** **que** l'agent immobilier...

or

> Elle a marchandé, **à tel point que** l'agent immobilier...

Is the usage of "tant et si bien" different somehow?

Also, whenever you use "tant et si bien", do you need to always have "que"  follow it?

Comment: It is [*tant et si bien **que***](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/tant_et_si_bien_que)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Tant et si bien que* et *à tel point que* sont des locutions conjonctives qui introduisent une conséquence. *Tant et si bien que* est de style légèrement plus soutenu et se rencontre plutôt à l'écrit.

> Nous n'avons pas aussitôt quitté le port que le bateau se met à rouler ou à tanguer (je n'ai jamais su faire la différence) tant et si bien que tous les passagers se cognent les uns les autres... (Extrait d'un roman contemporain, *Mélamine blues*, par François Gravel).
>
> Elle fait le plein des enfants, tant et si bien que ça se bouscule vraiment dans ce rectangle tout à fait sécurisé. (*[La Dépêche du Midi](http://www.ladepeche.fr/article/2016/07/30/2393227-inauguration-de-la-piscine-de-riviere.html)* - 30/07/2016)

À l'oral je dirais plutôt :

> Il y avait de la circulation, à tel point que j'ai raté mon train.

ou

> Il y avait de la circulation, si bien que j'ai raté mon train.

On peut aussi utiliser *si bien que* tout seul, auquel cas la virgule avant la subordonnée conjonctive est obligatoire.

> Elle a marchandé(,)tant et si bien que l'agent immobilier a diminué le prix de la maison de moitié.

> Elle a marchandé, si bien que l'agent immobilier a diminué le prix de la maison de moitié.

Si je ne mettais pas la virgule (ou à l'oral sans faire la pause) j'introduirais une nuance en mettant en relief la qualité du marchandage :

> Elle a marchandé si bien / que l'agent immobilier a diminué le prix de la maison de moitié.

Dans cette dernière phrase ce n'est pas le simple fait de marchander mais le fait d'avoir **bien** marchandé qui a fait céder l'agent immobilier.

Dans tous les cas le *que* est obligatoire.

*De telle manière que* est une autre locution conjonctive introduisant une conséquence et qui a le même sens.

> Elle a marchandé de telle manière que l'agent immobilier a diminué le prix de la maison de moitié.

---

Je ne dirais pas :

<strike>> Elle a marchandé tellement que l'agent immobilier...</strike>

mais je placerais *tellement* avant le verbe :

> Elle a tellement marchandé que l'agent immobilier...

on pourrait d'ailleurs avoir *tant* à la place de tellement ici.

> Elle a tant marchandé que l'agent immobilier...

cette construction rejoint celle ci-dessus avec « si bien marchandé que » mais au lieu d'insister sur la qualité, on insiste sur la quantité. Comme si elle avait eu l'agent immobilier à l'usure.

---

Pour répondre à la question posée en commentaire :
"**Is it possible to also use "assez... pour que..." and "trop... pour que..." in this context?**"

**trop/assez**... peuvent introduisent des propositions complétives de conséquence, mais le verbe de ces subordonnées est au subjonctif :

> Elle a assez marchandé pour que l'agent immobilier fasse un rabais sur le prix de la maison.
>
> Ils m'ont déjà raconté trop d'histoires pour que je les croie encore.

Attention : Si le sujet est le même dans les deux propositions alors le verbe de la subordonnée est à l'infinitif :

> J'avais assez faim pour manger finir le sandwich.
> J'étais trop inquiète pour pouvoir m’endormir.

Comment: To @Laure: Thank you for the most comprehensive explanation of various "**so... that...**" expressions. Is it possible to also use "**assez... pour que...**" and "**trop... pour que...**" in this context? I get the feeling that these two are somehow different in usage, though. Merci.

Comment: Hi. I get the feeling that the use of "si bien" sounds odd in the following instance: « Elle ***était pressée*** ce matin. ***Si bien*** qu’elle n’a même pas ... ». Perhaps, the presence of the verb "être" makes it so?

Comment: @Alone-zee Quite standard usage. You could rephrase the sentence; *elle était si pressée ce matin qu'elle n'a même pas...* No difference in meaning or use. I would not use a full stop, no punctuation.

Answer (score -1):

*Tant et si bien que* (yes, "que" is part of the idiom) actually means *so much and so well that* but it is outdated. This is the kind of idioms you would find in old stories.

> [...] le Grand Méchant Loup souffla, souffla, **tant et si bien que** la maison de paille s’envola. (Conte "Les trois petits cochons")

You are right, *tant et si bien que* is not different from *tellement que* or *à tel point que*.

Comment: I wouldn't say it's *that* outdated.